# Как в Angularjs реализуется мультиязычность

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo

Как влияет мультиязычность на SEO?
Как должен выглядеть URL, пример http://site.com/#/ru/home
Какие инструменты вы используете на своих проектах с angular для переключения языков?
Прочел пару статей аналогичных этой http://habrahabr.ru/post/237867/
http://fadeit.dk/blog/post/angularjs-seo-for-angular-translate
Но так и не нашел ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Какие инструменты вы используете на своих проектах с angular для переключения языков?

Модуль **[angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)**. Проект довольно активный и опытный. Документация неплохая. Можно сказать, что это выбор по умолчанию для мультиязычности в приложении angularjs.

> Как влияет мультиязычность на SEO?

Не хуже angular на мой взгляд. То есть препятствия на SEO приносит скорее angularjs а не именно мультиязычность. Тут, два варианта:

- Либо поисковый робот интерпретирует javascript, как [краулер Google с мая 2014](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), и тогда есть возможность, чтобы он индексирует страницу после рендера
- Либо поисковый робот не интерпретирует javascript. Тогда нужно как-нибудь давать краулеру уже обработанную версию страниц. Смотреть например [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) для этого.